# How to create a simple login authentication?

Tags: python, authentication, computer-science, except

How to create a simple login authentication?
These are my questions:

```
LOGIN AUTHENTICATION AND ACCESS CONTROL MODULE. 
Expand your system with user login and password authentication, the system should have 3 user types, which are admin, inventory-checker, and purchaser. 
ACCESS CONTROL: Each user type will be able to access or perform different functions of the system as follows: 
ADMIN: ALL Tasks. 
INVENTORY-CHECKER: STOCK TAKING, SEARCH ITEMS. 
PURCHASER: VIEW REPLENISH LIST, STOCK REPLENISHMENT, and SEARCH ITEMS. 
The user won’t be able to access the functions if he/she is not given the access right. 
LOGIN AUTHENTICATION: To perform the user authentication, you must create a few more functions to input the username, password, and user type as follows: 
1. ADD NEW USER: Only the Admin can perform this task. This function will allow the user to input the username, password, and user type. The data will be stored in a separate file. i.e. userdata.txt. For example: 

1 ahmad password admin 
2 lee abcd1111 inventory-checker 
2. USER AUTHENTICATION: This function will allow the user to key in a username and password. The function will read from the userdata.txt file and check the username and password. Please take note the username and password are case-sensitive. Users will only be able to log in with the correct username and password entered. Failed login will prompt the message: Incorrect password or username.
```

and these are my codes

```
import os
def add_new_user():
  """This function allows the user to input the username, password, and user type. The data will be stored in a separate file. i.e. userdata.txt."""

  username = input("Enter your username: ")
  password = input("Enter your password: ")
  user_type = input("Enter your user type (admin, inventory-checker, or purchaser): ")

  with open("userdata.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("%d %s %s\n" % (username, password, user_type))

def user_authentication():
  """This function allows the user to key in a username and password. The function will read from the userdata.txt file and check the username and password. Please take note the username and password are case-sensitive. Users will only be able to log in with the correct username and password entered. Failed login will prompt the message: Incorrect password or username."""

  username = input("Enter your username: ")
  password = input("Enter your password: ")

  with open("userdata.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
      user_data = line.split()
      if user_data[0] == username and user_data[1] == password:
        print("Login successful!")
        return user_data[2]

  print("Incorrect password or username.")
  return None

def main():
  """This function is the main function of the program. It will call the add_new_user() and user_authentication() functions."""

  while True:
    user_type = user_authentication()
    if user_type is None:
      continue

    if user_type == "admin":
      print("You are logged in as an admin.")
      # Do admin stuff here.
    elif user_type == "inventory-checker":
      print("You are logged in as an inventory checker.")
      # Do inventory checker stuff here.
    elif user_type == "purchaser":
      print("You are logged in as a purchaser.")
      # Do purchaser stuff here.

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

when I run the code the output I get is:
[image: img1]

[image: img2]

I tried running a `touchuserdata.txt` on the Windows terminal but it didn't work. I need assistance on how to fix these problems

Answer (score 0):

This works. However, you have to add break or exit() statements if you want the program to end after successful login.

```
def add_new_user():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    user_type = input("Enter your user type (admin, inventory-checker, or purchaser): ")
    with open("userdata.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write("%s %s %s\n" % (username, password, user_type))

def user_authentication():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    with open("userdata.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            user_data = line.split()
            if user_data[0] == username and user_data[1] == password:
                print("Login successful!")
                return user_data[2]
    print("Incorrect password or username.")
    return None

def main():
    add_new_user()
    while True:
        user_type = user_authentication()
        if user_type is None:
            continue
        if user_type == "admin":
            print("You are logged in as an admin.")
        elif user_type == "inventory-checker":
            print("You are logged in as an inventory checker.")
        elif user_type == "purchaser":
            print("You are logged in as a purchaser.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Take care of your newlines and indentations. These matter in python.